# Python 3.8.5 and MYSQLDB

Tags: python, mysql-python

As of late, I have been attempting to setup `MySQLDB` on Pycharm. I have Python 3.8.5 installed, have made sure the PATH is set, and everything seems to be working handily. After this, I ran the pip command.

`python -m pip install mysqldb`
and
`python -m pip install mysqldb-python`

But to no avail.

I tried to install it from Pycharm's interpreter page, but also no dice. I also attempted to install using a .whl file, but that has also turned out a failure. I've searched far and wide for the last few days, and I've found mention of this error, but none of the fixes I've seen have truly worked. The error I get is the same, regardless of which iteration I attempt to install. And of all the guides I see, I never see any mention of steps I've missed or things I should have done before attempting an installation aside from what I've done. The error is as follows.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQLdb (from versions: none)
DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQLdb (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MySQLdb
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try installing the following,

```
pip install pymysql
pip install mysql-connector
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

or you can go to lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python and install the wheels.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the wrong package to try to install mysqldb through pip. I tried it and got the same error you did this tells me that pip is looking for a package to download and install, but cannot find it.

Try this instead:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

You can learn more about this package here:
https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/#description